# Jargon for maximum/minumum absolute value in a set

Tags: terminology, absolute-value

Given a group of numbers $-5,-3,1,2$, the maximum is 2, the minimum is -5.

What is the mathematical jargon for the maximum and minimum in absolute terms (i.e. -5 and 1 respectively)?

Basically, I want to say that:

'-5 is the [jargon to mean maximum in absolute terms] in the group of numbers'.

I know that 'absolute maximum' generally refers to a global maximum in a context of a function. Is the phrase 'maximum absolute' used or easily confused with another meaning?

I appreciate this is a very basic question which probably has a really obvious answer but the answer escapes me...

Comment: I don't think there is "one word" for the term 'absolute maximum'. You can simply call it "absolute maximum".

Answer (score -1):

I would go with 'element with the greatest absolute value/magnitude', but as with any question like this, if there's any ambiguity about what you're saying, you're better off explaining it like you did here.

Comment: I was expecting that there is some jargon that was unambiguous and more succinct that what you or my question suggested...